# Wordpress localization of Blog articles - Possible?

Tags: wordpress, localization

I understand the basic concepts of setting up a Wordpress site for localization but what I don't understand is how to localize dynamic pages and blog posts.  Can you localize anything that isn't in the templates or plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See for instance the WPML plugin. Easily found with any search engine.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for.  I was unaware Wordpress didn't support this for content - only templates and plugins. Unfortunate. However, the license and cost is very reasonable and I love some of the features.